# trying to place a table inside a bootstrap row but the width of the table jumps across the row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I am trying to place a table inside a bootstrap row but the width of the table keeps jumping across the with of the table. I have added a maximum value of 50% to the width of the table but problem still persists.

this is the css of the table

**EDITTED*****

```
<div class="col-sm-10" style="min-height:280px">

            <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body"> 
    <style type="text/css">
            table {
                    max-width: 50%;
                    background-color: transparent;
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    border-spacing: 0;

                    }
                    .table thead th {
                    vertical-align: bottom;
                    }
                    .table th {
                    font-weight: bold;
                    }
                    .table th, .table td {
                    padding: 8px;
                    line-height: 20px;
                    text-align: left;
                    vertical-align: top;

                    }
                    .table td {
                      border-top: 1px solid #dddddd; 
                    }
                    table {
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    border-spacing: 0;
                    }
                    .table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td, .table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th {
                    background-color: #f9f9f9;
                    }
                    .table-bordered {
                    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
                    border-collapse: separate;
                    border-left: 0;
                    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
                    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
                    border-radius: 4px;
                    }
                    .table-bordered th, .table-bordered td {
                    border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
                    }
            </style>

then in my view i have html implementation of the css code in the jsp page

    <c:when test="${messageList != null}">
                 <c:forEach items="${messageList}" var="mesList">

                  <div class="row"> 


       <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr> 
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Message</th>
              <th>Time</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Mark</td>
              <td>${mesList.message}</td>
              <td>${mesList.timestamp}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
                 </div>                     


                </c:forEach>
                </c:when>

</div></div></div>
```

Please how can I place the table into the div row.

Comment: I don't think the table css is the problem. I tried what you posted and it looks fine. There is likely some css external to the table that is causing that. Can you post a more complete example?

Comment: @KhrisRoberts check to see my edits

Comment: remove row div see whats happening ... if you could put in jsfiddle

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue here - [Codepen](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/LRmxrA)

Comment: Here is what I'm seeing from your example. I'm still not seeing an issue. https://jsfiddle.net/khristopherallen/qjxadezp/

Comment: @Araz it is thesame

Comment: try to add this to css.  .table > tbody > tr > td:last-of-type{ max-width:150px }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `.table` is overriding the styles applied to the `table` tag. Apply your styles to the class `.table` rather than applying them to the tag `table`.

When dealing with stylesheet you always have to remember that they are cascading. The styles of a class will override the styles of the tag the class is applied to.

When your css has no effect it pays off to look in the developer tools of the browser. In Chrome, the styles that are being overridden will be marked out.

Comment: Replace this:    
  
`table {
  max-width: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}`  
  
with this:  
  
`.table {
  max-width: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}`

Comment: Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/melhoir/pen/yawvWy) snippet if you are still having issues.